# When plugging in a new screen it becomes the primary screen

Tags: windows-10

I have two monitors connected via DVI. I sometimes plug in my TV via HDMI. Whenever I do so it becomes the primary screen and after I remove the screen one of the two existing monitors randomly becomes the primary screen.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What type of graphics card are you using? It may have a settings app with some advanced profile and trigger settings that can override the Windows settings.

Comment: Also, is leaving the HDMI TV plugged in an option for you? If so, you could enable/disable using either Windows or the GPU's control panel settings instead of plugging/unplugging the cable each time.

Comment: @PFitz: it's an Nvidia card. Thanks for the tip - I tried playing around with the settings but nothing has come up so far.

Comment: @PFitz: It is plugged in all the time - to a receiver. But when I turn off the receiver or change the input, Windows treats it as the screen being disconnected.